# Do i need a new motor?

Tags: engine, chevrolet, monte-carlo

2001 monte carlo lost compression no water in the oil but oil in radiator.  Now the car wont start . Never overheated what could it be ? I have oil on the fans also

Comment: Sounds like a blown head gasket

Comment: How many miles on that engine? This does sounds like a blown head gasket.

Comment: There really isn't enough information here for us to tell you exactly what is wrong, but as the others have said it sure sounds like a bad head gasket(s). That doesn't necessarily mean the engine is ruined. Sometimes the head gaskets can be changed without further work as long as the engine isn't damaged. You will have to allow a mechanic to remove the heads to determine if there was any damage done.

Comment: On the contrary, it is plenty of information.  There is no other explanation except a blown head gasket.  Why is this question "put on hold"?  What other possible answers do CharlieRB, Chenmunka, and Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 anticipate?  Are these moderators qualified to be on this site?

Comment: @Carguy How can you **definitively** tell the OP they do or do not need a new engine with the provided information? Is there no other possible way oil can get into the coolant? By all means, if you can answer the question without a doubt, post an answer. Don't just complain.